# Select text from pdf in webview

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I am making a pdf using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo` from images,then loading that pdf into a `UIWebView`.

I want to select some text from that pdf and show it on a textview. Here is the code sample I am using to load a pdf on a web view.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images.pdf"];

NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSLog(@"pdf URL :: %@",pdfUrl);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

I have tried using the following, but it is returning a blank string.

```
NSString *innerText = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerText"];
```

edit:: I want the text selection functionality as implemented in ibooks.

Comment: document.documentElement.innerText is the way to go. but you can't read the text from the PDF using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

can you see this example in gitHub: https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten

Comment: i have seen into this but there is no information as to how select particular text from a pdf.